# How to implement one interface in an other

Tags: angular

I am putting together my service structure for my Angular 4 application and have come across an issue.

I am wanting to call a GET request on my API which will return me a `User`, but inside that user it should also return a list of `Applications`

I have created an `User.service.ts` which looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getAllUsers(){
    }

    getUserById(){

    }

    createUser(){            
    }       
}
```

So when I call getUserById it will return me a User object for which I have created an interface:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Email: string;
    Role: string;
    Applications: //LIST OF APPLICATIONS
}
```

How do I get the Applications property linked up to my Application.ts file?

Comment: Like `Applications: Array<Application>`?

Comment: I don't understand the question....

Comment: @ExplosionPills So I just need to import the Applications.ts file at the top of the class and then add Array<Applications> ?

Comment: @BenClarke Yes, that's it.

Comment: @n00dl3 Oh why did i think it was much more complicated than that. My bad ... Do you want to write an answer with a resolution to mark as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "List," you probably mean Array (first class JavaScript construct), so you probably want to use an Array of `Application` types.

```
import { Application } from './application.interface';

export interface User {
  /* ...other properties... */
  Applications: Array<Application>;
}
```

Note that you could also write this as `Application[]` and it would mean the same thing. It's up to you. I prefer the former since there is no analogous shortcut for other generics. For instance, you *must* write `Observable<Application>`.

Now when assigning to or reading from `userInstance.Applications`, each property of the array is assumed to be an Application.

Assuming your `Application` interface is something very simple like `{ id: number,  name: string }`, keep in mind the following:

```
// not allowed
userInstance.Applications.push(notAnApplication);
userInstance.Applications[0].otherProperty;

// allowed
userInstance.Applications[1].id;
userInstance.Applications.push({ id, name } as Application);
```

Also note that `[Application]` as a type declaration is *not* the same. This would be an array that has a single property that is of type `Application`.

You can read more about generics in Typescript here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 3):

Just make it an array of applications:

```
Applications: Application[]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your code file

```
import { Application } from './Application';
```

*make sure Application is exported in `Application.ts`*

And then your interface add

```
Applications: Application[];
```

Also

- Do not forget to use `export` so that types can be accessed outside of the file they are declared in.
- Mark the return types on your methods, I omitted `CreateUser` because it was not clear if it returned anything or took in a parameter.

Complete code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Application } from './Application';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getAllUsers() : Observable<User[]> {
    }
    getUserById() : Observable<User> {
    }
}


export interface User {
    id: string;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Email: string;
    Role: string;
    Applications: Application[];
}
```